# 2 types that represent the closed generic type IQueryHandler

Tags: c#, simple-injector

Given the following:-

```
public abstract class PriceBookDataViewModelQuery : IQuery<PriceBookDataViewModel>
{
    public bool IsRenewal { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}


public class PriceBookDataSseElecViewModelQuery : PriceBookDataViewModelQuery
{
}


public class PriceBookDataSseGasViewModelQuery : PriceBookDataViewModelQuery
{
}

public interface IQueryHandler<in TQuery, out TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    TResult Handle(TQuery query);
}
```

and in my container config I have

```
Container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
  typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).Assembly);
```

My query handlers are:-

```
public class PriceBookDataSseElecViewModelHandler :
    IQueryHandler<PriceBookDataViewModelQuery, PriceBookDataViewModel>

public class PriceBookDataSseGasViewModelHandler : 
    IQueryHandler<PriceBookDataViewModelQuery, PriceBookDataViewModel>
```

I get the error following message:

> There are 2 types that represent the closed generic type
>   IQueryHandler. Types: PriceBookDataSseElecViewModelHandler and
>   PriceBookDataSseGasViewModelHandler. Either remove one of the types or
>   use an overload that takes an BatchRegistrationCallback delegate

I understand why this happens as I have two types that inherit from the same IQueryHandler. However eventually I will have around 20 of these queries that will contain the same properties so aiming to stay dry.

What options do I have apart from duplicating properties on 20 query classes? How do I use a `BatchRegistrationCallback` in my scenario?

Comment: What happens if you move the `IQuery<PriceBookDataViewModel>` interface reference to each subclass?

Comment: Please show your query handlers.

Comment: Added query handlers

Comment: What is the difference in the two classes other than the name?  Is there another type that distinguishes them that could be added to the generic interface definition?

Comment: Yes its all open for debate and can be changed. So I add a type how do I wire up the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the fear of being a bit confused about this question, heres what I have to say:

> I understand why this happens as I have two types that inherit from the same IQueryHandler. However eventually I will have around 20 of these queries that will contain the same properties so aiming to stay dry.

If you have multiple handlers with the same properties, why not just move the shared properties out in an abstract class and define separate and unique handlers?

Sometimes I like to think "DRY" as "Do Repeat Yourself", if it works and is easy to maintain and understand, do repeat yourself. It does not matter you have 10 classes more since they are separated into single responsibility.

```
public abstract class PriceBookDataViewModelQuery  {

    public bool IsRenewal { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }   
}

public PriceBookDataSseElecViewModelQuery
    : IQuery<PriceBookDataViewModel>, PriceBookDataViewModelQuery {

    // Extra properties
}

public class PriceBookDataSseGasViewModelQuery
    : IQuery<PriceBookDataViewModel>, PriceBookDataViewModelQuery
{
    // Extra properties
}

// First handler 
public class PriceBookDataSseElecViewModelHandler
    : IQueryHandler<PriceBookDataSseElecViewModelQuery, PriceBookDataViewModel>
{
}

// Second handler
public class PriceBookDataSseGasViewModelHandler
    : IQueryHandler<PriceBookDataSseGasViewModelQuery, PriceBookDataViewModel> 
{
}
```